# Rewriting the Landau equation

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics

I read an introduction to Landau equation:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d} \vert A\rvert^2}{\mathrm{d}t}=2\sigma \lvert A \rvert^2 - \ell \lvert A \rvert^4.$$
And I encountered a problem on the solution of the simple model equation.

By dividing $-\lvert A \rvert ^4$, I have
$$-\frac{1}{\vert A \rvert^4}\frac{\mathrm{d} \vert A \rvert ^2}{\mathrm{d} t}+2 \sigma \vert A \rvert ^{-2} = \ell$$

Can somebody can tell me how this form can be rewritten as

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} \lvert A \rvert ^{-2}}{\mathrm{d}t}+2 \sigma \lvert A \rvert ^{-2} = \ell,$$
as shown in the following excerpt of the textbook. Thank you in advance!

> Landau described the instability by the equation
>   \begin{equation}
> \tag{49.3}
>     \mathrm{d} |A|^2 / \mathrm{d} t
>   = 2 \sigma |A|^2 - \ell |A|^4
> \end{equation}
>   for the amplitude $|A|$ of the dominant mode, where $\ell$ is some constant, now called the *Landau constant*.
>   Also equation $(49.3)$ is called the *Landau equation*, although it is equivalent to the logistic equation in the theory of population growth.
>   (We shall see that it is more properly regarded as a truncation of a system of ordinary differential equations whose other terms are often, but not always, negligible in hydrodynamic stability.)
>   Of course if $\ell$ were zero equation $(49.3)$ would reduce to the equation given by the linear theory.
>   The second term on the right-hand side of equation $(49.3)$ is due to the nonlinearity and may moderate or accelerate the exponential growth of the linear disturbance according to the signs of $\sigma$ and $\ell$.
>
> Rewriting the Landau equation as a linear equation in $|A|^{-2}$, namely
>   $$
>     \frac{\mathrm{d}|A|^{-2}}{\mathrm{d}t}
>   + 2 \sigma |A|^{-2}
>   = \ell,
> $$
>   we find the explicit general solution
>   $$
>     |A|^{-2}
>   = \ell/2\sigma + (A_0^{-2} - \ell/2\sigma) e^{-2 \sigma t}.
> $$
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCvOv.png).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the chain rule to compute 
$$
\frac{d}{dt} |A|^{-2} = \frac{d}{dt} (|A|^2)^{-1} = -1(|A|^2)^{-2} \frac{d}{dt} |A|^2 = -|A|^{-4} \frac{d}{dt} |A^2| = l - 2 \sigma |A|^{-2}.
$$
Then we use standard ODE to solve the equation
$$
\frac{d}{dt} z + 2\sigma z = l
$$
as in the picture and then plug in $z = |A|^{-2}$.